# Fastest way to update product information in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

Which approach is better and fast to update bulk product update in magento 2.3+ ? e.g i want to update 1000+ products at a time using cron job or command line

please suggest

Comment: What type of information you want to update ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeIds = array_keys($storeManager->getStores());
$action = objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action');
$updateAttributes['name'] = "test";
$updateAttributes['price'] = 100;
$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', 'A960-CQ');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach ($collection as $product) 
{
    foreach ($storeIds as $storeId) {
        $action->updateAttributes([$product->getId()], $updateAttributes, $storeId);
    }
}
```

Comment: We can use “updateAttributes” method to update Specific Attribute for product instead update all the data

You can pass multiple attribute that you want to updates detail.As show price and name are pass in an array and updateAttributes will update the name and price of the product